# Can you extend Playwright Page() Python sync?

Tags: python-asyncio, playwright, playwright-python

I'm testing out Playwright (Python) and there are a bunch of additional methods that I want to attach to the Page(). I tried inheriting the class but keep getting `_init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'impl_obj'` What is this impl_obj and what is the best way to extend methods to their Page()

```
from playwright.sync_api import Page

class CustomPage(Page):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def test(self):
        print('test')

page = CustomPage()

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'impl_obj'
```

Comment: This is not supported, we recommend wrapping the class instead and accepting a page instance inside the constructor.

Comment: @MaxSchmitt Do you have an example of how you would do this? I tried to yield the page class within the constructor but the page instance will get event loop is closed when trying to run it.

Comment: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/pom

Comment: @MaxSchmitt  we are not allowed to extend either Page or Browser? We were moving away from Pyppeteer, needed backward compatibility, for existing use cases.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, no. You can only wrapped class
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet/issues/2090

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34500486)